# how to make pre-set public property to private while creating a custom control

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, custom-controls

I am creating a custom MaskedTextBox for Date only. Now i want to hide Mask property of MaskedTextBox from its users.

**EDIT:**

```
public class CustomDateMask:System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
    {

        public new string Mask
        {
           get;
           private set;
        }

        public  CustomDateMask()
        {
            this.Mask = @"00/00/2\000"; // this property should not be set by any one now
            this.ValidatingType = typeof(System.DateTime); // this property should not be set by any one now
        }
   }
```

What should i do so that no one can set this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste this into your class:

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public new string Mask {
    get { return base.Mask; }
    set { base.Mask = value; }
}
```

The [Browsable] attribute hides the property in the Properties window.  The [EditorBrowsable] attribute hides it from IntelliSense.

Comment: @nobugz: do we need to use any namespace also for browsable

Comment: using System.ComponentModel;  Visual Studio 2008 should prompt you add it automatically though....

Answer (score 4):

You can't completely remove it without breaking the [Liskov substitution principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); but you could re-declare it and hide it (either make it non-browsable or make the setter private).

But IMO it is a bad idea; wrapping the control would be cleaner.

Note that member-hiding can be easily avoided (without even realising) simply by casting as the base-type.

Comment: Wrapping the control is the "right" way to do this, since this date box is *not* a `MaskedTextBox` .  And you avoid the cast-as-base-type problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public class Test : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
 {
    public new string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text; }
        private set { base.Text = value; }
    }

    public Test()
    {
      base.Text = "hello";
    }
 }


 Test test = new Test(); // Create an instance of it
 string text = test.Text;
 text.Text = "hello world"; // comp error
```

**Error Details:**

Error 1 The property or indexer 'ScratchPad.Test.Text' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible C:\@Dev\ScratchPad\ScratchPad\ScratchPad\Form1.cs 33 13 ScratchPad

Comment: This is a: easily avoided by casting to the base type, and b: doesn't return the (base) mask at all.

Comment: @gmcalab: Even after doing this, I am able to set Mask Property. It hasn't hidden yet

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta, I dont know what you did but I update mine to show the whole code. It errors for me if i try to set it.

Comment: you are right, it shows error. I was thinking that it should get hidden from property window which was answered by "nobugz" but your answer is also correct. Thx